# Flutter get Download Url from Firebase Storage

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to load a thumbnail image from Firebase Storage, to improve the performance of my app. Once the thumbnail is loaded, the actual image should be displayed. For that reason I implemented a Cloud Function, which automatically uploads a thumbnail for each image.

I have no Problem with getting the download url from the uploaded image. But because of the reason, that the generation of the thumbnail takes 3 sec, I can not automatically retrieve the download Url from the thumbnail.

Here is what I came up so far:

```
   Future uploadImage(var imageFile) async {

 var uuid = new Uuid().v1();
 StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post_$uuid.jpg");
 StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
 String downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();

 StorageReference reff = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("thumb_post_$uuid.jpg");
 String url = (await reff.getDownloadURL()).toString();

 setState(() {
   downloadUrlThumb = url;
   downloadUrlFull = downloadUrl;
 });
}
```

Any idea on how I can wait for the uploaded thumbnail or on how I can delay the `getDownloadURL()` method for the `downloadUrlThumb()`?

Comment: Please use the correct product names. As far as I can see you're using Cloud Storage for Firebase, and Cloud Functions (to generate the thumbnails). Neither of those is Firestore, which is a NoSQL database and doesn't seem to be relevant to this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a record into the database when thumbnail creation is completed
and subscribe to updates for that table to get notified in the client app when the record was added.
If you write the path of the uploaded file (or the thumbnails path) to the database you can identify which upload/thumbnail-creation was completed.

Comment: can help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743626/nosuchmethoderror-the-method-listen-was-called-on-null-e-flutter-10609-re/57744782?noredirect=1#comment101927797_57744782

Answer (score 0):

In the cloud function you can save the url into firestore after the thumbnail has been generated.

example: 
After record has been saved

```
{
   hello: "world",
   imageUrl: "asldnbalskd.firebase.storage.com"
}
```

around 5 seconds later when thumbnail is generated

```
{
   hello: "world",
   imageUrl: "asldnbalskd.firebase.storage.com",
   imageUrlThumbnail: "thumbnail-asldnbalskd.firebase.storage.com"
}
```

In the flutter side you can just listen to the document for any changes.